# How to efficiently supervise Ruby Threads?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Is the following inefficient? I want to allocate nearly all resources to threads but I'm wondering if in this case this loop will consume a lot of CPU time.

Thanks!

```
threads = create_threads #method that returns an Array of Threads
loop do
  alive = false
  threads.each do |thread|
    if thread.alive?
      alive = true
    end
  end
  break unless alive
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
threads.each do |thread|
  thread.join
end
```

Comment: But that defeats multi-threading as concurrency is effectively disabled. I still want Ruby to switch between the main thread, thread 1, thread 2, etc

Comment: It still switches between the threads, it jut waits until they're all finished before continuing. If thread1 is long running and thread2 isn't and we're waiting on a join on thread1, thread2 will continue to execute and finish. When thread1 is finished we'll call join on thread2 which will immediately return.

Comment: Hi Farrel,

You're right, the other threads continue to execute. This example clarified it for me.

http://pastebin.org/90678

Answer (score 3):

```
threads.each &:join
```

`my_thread.join` returns as soon as `my_thread` exits.